# Kotlin stopped recognizing object tag

Tags: android, kotlin

I upgraded Android Studio and now my project fails to compile.

I'm hitting `org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression at (23,34) in .../SomeFragment.kt`

```
var amounts: MutableList<Int?> = object : ArrayList<Int?>() {
     init {
         add(50)
         add(100)
         add(150)
         add(null)
     }
 }
```

which is complaining the `object` tag. Changing to

`var amounts: MutableList<Int?> = arrayListOf(50, 100, 150, null)`

works fine, but I have a lot of my other *.kt files using this `object :` in initialization.

I'm using:

```
Android Studio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

#### UPDATE

In `Tools > Kotlin > Kotlin Updates`, I'm already using the latest kotlin `1.2.61-release-Studio3.1-1`.

Tried:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart,
- Sync with File System,
- Sync Project with Gradle Files,
- Clean Project & Rebuild Project,
- Restart Android Studio
- Removed `.git`, `.gradle`, and `.idea` in project directory,
- Removed `~/.AndroidStudio3.1` directory
- Removed `~/.android` directory

but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing `~/.gradle` directory. (in my case, it's the `C:\Users\{User}\.gradle` in Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade to latest Kotlin version
2. Perform a clean rebuild as this could be caused by incremental builds.